# Not able check in web.config in TFS 2012

Tags: web-config

We have issue with web.config files in all our web projects. 
I can check out, modify and check in any other files, accept web.config - we have to bypass build during check in process for our web.config files. Error return by 
`TFS build: Exception Message: Access to the path 'C:\Builds\2\89\Sources\..\WebProjectName\Web.config' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException)` 
I check permission - no issue there. 
please advice?

Comment: 30 min after I publish this question, I found solution. after I change build template from ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml to DefaultTemplete.11.1.xaml - issue resolved by them self.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other applications/services are reading that file.  Maybe IIS, notepad or some other app has a lock on the file?